# working .dat extension file in android

Tags: android

I need to use a file of type .dat in Android, but I cannot reference to the file ,application doesnt realize that file

Is that code correct?

```
File sdcard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  File file=new File(sdcard,"dictionary.dat");
  if(file.exists()){
         Toast.makeText(context,"file exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
  else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"NOT exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 String path=file.getAbsolutePath();    
 FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(path);
 DataInputStream dawgDataFile=new DataInputStream(fis);
```

maybe I coded in wrong way, I just need to use "dictionary.dat" file , and I have stored it in raw folder. Button application says "NOT exists" . help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot get a file saved in **RAW** folder like that. This is how you can do it:

```
InputStream inputStream  = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dictionary);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

//then start reading lines from reader with reader.readLine()
```

*P.S. when saving files in RAW folder, file extensions can be omitted as they are not available when referencing in code*